# File cannot be deleted due to being used by System

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, process, file-management

I have a file I can't delete as "it is used by System". I tried rebooting, turning off and on, then I tried using Revo Uninstaller forced delete and FileAssassin, but none of them worked. I checked if it was a virus using ESET 9 but the file is not infected, it is just "used by System" and cannot be deleted. Any ideas on removing that file?

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10 64 bit. The file itself is a file I made into a `.bin` some time ago, nothing important. I did close `Daemon` of course, still no clue why System uses it.

Comment: Which file is it?  Perhaps, it's an important system file

Comment: Nope, a file I made into a `.bin` some time ago. It isn't affected by `Daemon` as I exited that one.

Comment: Funny useless fact: @Steven is also my name ;)   But in link with the question: It would be good to know what kind of file it is, what it does, etc.  Also, Have you tried deleting the file from CMD ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file as SYSTEM.

1. Download the Microsoft Utility [PsTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649)
2. Open a command prompt as Administrator
3. Run `psexec -s cmd`
4. Run `whoami` to confirm you are `nt authority\system`
5. `del yourfile.bin`

Answer (score 0):

If you restart the PC into safe mode it will allow you to remove stubborn files in most cases. The other option is to disable services that aren't system critical then try and remove the file. The only thing I would say about option 2 is that there are a lot of services and trying to find the one that's using the file is like trying to find a needle in a hay stack.

Restarting into Safe Mode:

Press WinKey + R

Type "msconfig"

Click on the Boot tab

Click Safe Mode

Click Ok

Click Restart

Once the PC boots, login and try deleting your file.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to delete the file, but instead just replace the contents, you can typically rename it and replace it:

```
move thefile.bin notthefile.bin
notepad thefile.bin
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please post comments in their appropriate location and reserve this area for answers.

Comment: @music2myear I think most people with this problem want to change `C:\thefile.bin` or make it so there is no file at that path, and don't really care about a locked file object if it's moved to `%TMP%` -- it's an XY problem.